# Scrapy- Finding the correct CSS selectors

Tags: python, css, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import LowesspiderItem


class LowesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lowes'
    #allowed_domains = ['lowes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.css('.grid-container')
        for product in items:
            item = LowesspiderItem()

        #get product price
            productPrice = product.css('.art-pd-price::text').getall()


            item["productPrice"] = productPrice


            yield item
```

Here is how I got the selectors:
[image]

[image]

I'm still a little confused on how to find the correct selectors when looking at the html of a website. I'm finding the top level item by scrolling to the top and finding all items that are highlighted. Then I use the CSS selector extension on google chrome to find the specific elements I want to scrape. The program should be giving me the price back, but I have no results yielded. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: These days most sites are using front-end frameworks, which means you can either * use splash, * pull it out of some json, or * switch to selenium / puppeteer

Comment: @pguardiario wouldn't pulling selectors be fine too, I did that for another website and that spider works fine

Comment: No because if you view the page source you will see they aren't really there.

Comment: @pguardiario I see do you have any resources that I can look into for scraping this website? I'd prefer to use scrapy + splash or pull it from json

Comment: I would just google for ScrapySplash and find a good tutorial.

Comment: and how would I pull it from the json

Comment: with json.loads

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for recommending scrapy + splash! I think I have a direction to go now. Also how did you know this website is using a front end framework? Is it because it never explicitly states the attributes of each product? I'm not too familiar with Front End stuff so I'd appreciate if you could tell me what to look for when I'm scraping other websites.

Comment: Basically don't trust the elements panel, you have to look at the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're missing the location of the store so you can just have to add a location cookie